# Sort mongo results if a value exists in the field or not

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mongo-go

I have a Student struct which looks like this.

```
type Student struct {
    Name            string                         `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Marks           int                            `json:"marks" bson:"marks"`
    Subjects        []string                       `json:"subjects" bson:"subjects"`
}
```

I am using `opts.Sort` to [Sort](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/v1.11.1/mongo/options/findoptions.go#L105) the result. More on that

```
opts.Sort = bson.D{
    {Key: "marks", Value: -1},
}
```

I also want to sort the results by `Subjects`, in a way that, if for any Student, if the subject `Math` exist, it should be sorted on top (descending order), before sorting it by `marks`
I tried doing this

```
opts.Sort = bson.D{
    {Key: "subjects", Value: bson.M{"$in": "math"}},
    {Key: "marks", Value: -1},
}
```

I know this doesn't seem right because I am not passing 1 or -1 but I don't know how can I modify it to make it work.
What am I missing here?.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a single "simple" query.

Query the records sorted by `marks`, and do a second sorting in Go, by moving documents having `"math"` subject to the front.

If you need to do this only in MongoDB, you may redesign: e.g. you may add a boolean field to documents storing the information whether the student has `"math"`, so you can easily include that in sorting.

Do note however that you may do this with the [Aggregation framework](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/). This is the query that would do what you need:

```
db.students.aggregate(
    {$addFields:{"hasMath": {$in:["math", "$subjects"]}}},
    {$sort:{hasMath: -1, marks: -1}}
)
```

What this does is essentially what I suggested: it adds a `hasMath` field, telling if the student has `"math"` in the `subjects` array, and then sorts documents first by `hasMath` descending, then by marks descending.

This is how you can do that in Go using the official mongo-go driver:

```
c := ... // Obtain students collection

pipe := []bson.M{
    {"$addFields": bson.M{
        "hasMath": bson.M{"$in": []any{"math", "$subjects"}},
    }},
    {"$sort": bson.D{
        {Key: "hasMath", Value: -1},
        {Key: "marks", Value: -1},
    }},
}

curs, err := c.Aggregate(ctx, pipe)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
    panic(err)
}

var students []Student
if err := curs.All(ctx, &students); err != nil {
    // Handle error
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Thanks you!. I never thought about adding a new field as it can be a big change and can affect a lot of APIs using this method unfortunately. How can I do a "second Sorting".I am a bit lost here, thanks

Comment: @RajatSingh The second part of the answer solves your task using the Aggregation framework. This doesn't require you to change anything in the database, the field is only created during the aggregation execution.

Comment: just one doubt, are you sure we have to use `{"$sort": bson.D{{"hasBoostTags", -1}}}`  and not `{"$sort": bson.D{{Key: "hasBoostTags", Value: -1}}},` ?. I get a warning `primitive.E struct literal uses unkeyed fields`

Comment: @RajatSingh That is just a warning, it's recommended to use named key literals. It's just a warning, the code means the same. Do use it if you want to get rid of the warning. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I just found out that we also gonna use this sorting on an another collection, using `Find()`, is there's any way to extend the code or any other ways what you talked about `do a second sorting in Go`, how can I do it, I am pretty new to Mongo and trying to read the docs and understand but didn't made any progress.

Comment: @RajatSingh You can use this "technique" on any collection. Without specifics I can't give a more specific answer.